# Why is "Version" an unknown parameter in a Timestream record?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I decided to upsert some data, for which purpose the Timestream documentation suggests that I include a version in my records.

However, when I do so, I get the following error:

""Parameter validation failed:\nUnknown parameter in Records[0]: \"Version\", must be one of: Dimensions, MeasureName, MeasureValue, MeasureValueType, Time, TimeUnit...

I'm invoking Timestream from a lambda function using Python 3.8.

Is it possibly a version issue (I'm using v1.16.31 of the AWS Python SDK.)? Or maybe because the initial records didn't have a Version specified, it thinks I'm violating the schema?

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    session = boto3.Session()
    #
    # Write data
    write_client = session.client(
        'timestream-write', 
        config=Config(
            read_timeout=20, 
            max_pool_connections=5000,
            retries={'max_attempts': 10}
        )
    )
    try:
        result = write_client.write_records(
            DatabaseName=event['database_name'], 
            TableName=event['table_name'],
            Records=event['records'], 
            CommonAttributes={}
        ) 
        return {
            'statusCode': result['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'],
            'body': json.dumps(result)
        }
        
    except write_client.exceptions.RejectedRecordsException as err:
        
        return {
            'statusCode': 400,
            'body': json.dumps(err.response['RejectedRecords'])
        }
    except Exception as err:
        return {
            'statusCode': 400,
            'body': json.dumps(str(err))
        }
```

The recommendation to use "Version" in this way is given here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/code-samples.write.html

### Edit

In the meantime, I've resorted to storing the timestamp of the last written record as an AWS Secret, and using this to toss repeated data before writing new records. Not efficient.

Comment: Can you show your lambda function and how do you " invoking Timestream from a lambda function"?

Comment: Updated, @Marcin. My record has a key:value "Version":time_in_milliseconds

Comment: Thanks. What is your `event['records']`?

Comment: a list of timestream records (dict objects with key:value pairs)

Comment: The error message indicates they are in the incorrect format. Without seeing them, its difficult to confirm this.

Comment: I don't think that's necessary. They exhaustively list the permissible keys, and Version is not included amongst them. The question is "why?" since they include it in the documentation.